# Algorithm to find roots of a "bidimensional function"

Tags: algorithms, searching

The object I am studying is a bit more complicated than a bidimensional function, but I think I can explain what I need better with a simplified example. I can provide more details if asked.

So imagine I have a function of two variables with real output, $f(x,y)$, and I know that, $f(x_0, y_0) = 0$. Now I also know that this function has a one-dimensional root, i.e. $f(x,y(x)) = 0$. Now I wish to take start from $x_0$, $y_0$, $y(x)$. Now given a value of $x$ and a sufficiently accurate guess for $y$, I use a Newton algorithm on $g(y) = f(x, y)$ and find the root. Hence, my approach is to take $g_n(y) = f(x_{n-1}, y)$ and use $y_{n-1}$ as a seed to the Newton algorithm. If I vary $x$ sufficiently slowly, then I should not have an issue finding the values for $y$.

Now, the question is, what is the best way to vary $x$? I know I could choose $x_{n+1} = x_n + h$, with fixed $h$, but I would like to be able to vary the value of $h$ to take into consideration the local structure of $f$.

I am not sure if this was very clear, I can give further clarification if requested. Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: Okay, you would like to be flexible about picking h. How to pick h? It depends on what do you want. Probably if y(x) grows too fast you may want to pick smaller h.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: Exactly, I would want the algorithm to use the shape of y(x) inferred so far, and taking some numerical derivative, or related, decide how big should h be. This is quite important, because at some point the function starts varying fast, and I need to take smaller steps. I am thinking of doing some ad-hoc $h_n= 2\,  h_0/\, |y'(x_{n-1}) / y'(x_0) + 1|$, but was wondering if there is some standard way to approach such problems

Comment: I see. I am not sure I can help

Comment: I think I found an approach that will help me. Will reply later